# How to create a list of colors for perlin-noise (2d)?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, rgb

So I have a function, `make-noise` that gets the *coordinates* of a pixel and creates on that position the noise value.

Now I want to create a map with four colors. Blue for water, yellow for sand, green for grass and grey for mountains... The generated noise-value is a height indication.

I want to have a function `create-map: number(width) number(height) -> (list of color)` How can I do this?  . How can I create a list of colors based on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Write a function that maps heights to colours and apply it the noise.

Comment: I don't  understand. And what do you mean by "apply it the noise".  Noise gives out just a value, not a color. And my `make-noise` function gets just two coordinates x and y.

Comment: You have a function from coordinates to heights. If you write a function from heights to colours, you can use them together in order to get a function from coordinates to colours.

Comment: Ok. Now I need to find out how to handle the amount of coordinates. Does that mean, if width and height are both 512, I would have 512*512 Pixels?

Comment: What code have you tried?